# How to use visual studio 2015 or 2017 free?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just want to create a simple console application in Visual studio 2015 or 2017. But visual studio is not freely available. I tried to download VS2017 trial version but I am only getting one installed template and that is to create blank solution. Please suggest what I need to do or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You could try looking for and installing the community edition which is the equivalent to the pro version.

Comment: When you install vs2017 make sure you check the box for desktop development

Comment: Thanks Scott. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not in an enterprise, you can download and use VS Community for Free

(Formerly Visual Studio express)

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Comment: I have already installed it. But when I go to create new project only blank solution is coming under installed templates.